# C: How to insert string inside a grid of characters

Tags: c

I am trying to make a search word puzzle where the program chooses at random 4 words for the user to find. So far I have created the grid with random characters and made a list of random words that are printed below the grid. I've tried using strcpy to insert the words inside the grid but have not managed to succeed. Any help would be appreciated. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

char randomChar(){
int r = (rand() % 26) + 65;
return r;
//return char(r);
}

int main(void){

int randomNum = 0;
char grid[11][11];
const char *chosenWords[4];
const char *words[20]={"DOG", "CAT", "PENCIL", "BOOK", "PAPER", "CLOUD", "RAIN", "SUN", "MOON", "MIRROR", "BUBBLE", "GOLD", "SILVER", "APPLE", "KIWI", "RED", "BLUE", "GREEN", "YELLOW"};

printf("\tA\tB\tC\tD\tE\tF\tG\tH\tI\tJ\n\n");
for(int i=1; i<11; i++){
    printf("%d\t", i);

    for(int j=0; j<10; j++){
        char c=randomChar();
        grid[i][j]=c;
        printf("%c\t", *(&(grid[i][j])));
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}

for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
    int flag=0;
    do{
        randomNum = (rand()%20);
        chosenWords[i]=words[randomNum];
        flag=0;
        for(int j=0;j<i;j++){
            if(strcmp(words[randomNum],chosenWords[j])==0)flag=1;
        }
    }while(flag);
    //grid[(rand()%20)+1][(rand()%20)+1];
    printf("%s\n", words[randomNum]);
}



getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You say that you tried with strcpy. I don't see that in your code. Show your failed attempt.

Comment: You definitely don't want to use `strcpy` as it will copy the NUL terminating character as well overwriting a potentially valid character in the grid.

Comment: it'll be much easier to read if you wrote `rand() % 26 + 'A'`. Who knows what 65 is? Btw you didn't seed the random sequence with `srand`

Comment: Use strcpy for the line 
        chosenWords[i]=words[randomNum]

Comment: Your code doesn't prevent accidentally including words from your list.